# I don't understand how works function (Builder $query) in Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, query-builder

I have the following function to find products with same colors from my table `Product_Colors` and it works fine:

```
$colors = ProductColor::query()->
select('color_id', DB::raw("count(*) as amount"))
    ->groupBy('color_id')
    ->having('amount','>=', '3')
    ->get();
```

And I have many-to-many relationship :

```
public function colors() {
   return $this->belongsToMany('App\Color','product_colors');
}
```

now I want to get every product that have the same 3 colors.
I have this query :

```
$products = Product::whereHas('colors', function(Builder $query) { $query
    ->groupBy('color_id', 'product_id');},'>', '3')->get();
```

and I get nothing, but I am sure that I have two products with 3 same colors. Can someone help me, to give a hint about what am I doing wrong?

I have the following code to get all projects which have more than 3 colors:

```
        $products = Product::has('colors', '>', 3)->with('colors')->get();
```

But I need all that have more than 3 colors with exact same colors
for instance:

```
    "products": [
    {
        "id": 2,
        "title": "net",
        "created_at": "2019-10-08 07:36:42",
        "updated_at": "2019-10-08 07:36:42",
        "colors": [
            {
                "id": 16,
                "name": "Peru",
                "created_at": "2019-10-08 07:36:42",
                "updated_at": "2019-10-08 07:36:42",
                "pivot": {
                    "product_id": 2,
                    "color_id": 16
                }
            },
            {
                "id": 17,
                "name": "Red",
                "created_at": "2019-10-08 07:36:42",
                "updated_at": "2019-10-08 07:36:42",
                "pivot": {
                    "product_id": 2,
                    "color_id": 17
                }
            },
            {
                "id": 20,
                "name": "DarkTurquoise",
                "created_at": "2019-10-08 07:36:42",
                "updated_at": "2019-10-08 07:36:42",
                "pivot": {
                    "product_id": 2,
                    "color_id": 20
                }
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "MediumPurple",
                "created_at": "2019-10-08 07:36:42",
                "updated_at": "2019-10-08 07:36:42",
                "pivot": {
                    "product_id": 2,
                    "color_id": 2
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "title": "org",
        "created_at": "2019-10-08 07:36:42",
        "updated_at": "2019-10-08 07:36:42",
        "colors": [
            {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "MediumPurple",
                "created_at": "2019-10-08 07:36:42",
                "updated_at": "2019-10-08 07:36:42",
                "pivot": {
                    "product_id": 3,
                    "color_id": 2
                }
            },
            {
                "id": 16,
                "name": "Peru",
                "created_at": "2019-10-08 07:36:42",
                "updated_at": "2019-10-08 07:36:42",
                "pivot": {
                    "product_id": 3,
                    "color_id": 16
                }
            },
            {
                "id": 17,
                "name": "Red",
                "created_at": "2019-10-08 07:36:42",
                "updated_at": "2019-10-08 07:36:42",
                "pivot": {
                    "product_id": 3,
                    "color_id": 17
                }
            },
            {
                "id": 20,
                "name": "DarkTurquoise",
                "created_at": "2019-10-08 07:36:42",
                "updated_at": "2019-10-08 07:36:42",
                "pivot": {
                    "product_id": 3,
                    "color_id": 20
                }
            }
        ]
    },
```

Comment: what logic is behind "all that have more than 3 colors with exact same colors", what happen if there is two sets of group of color that satisfies this condition ?

Comment: It's a task for me. this code doesn't continue with a logic.
it's just an exercise to understand better laravel query builder

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that you can supply the checks on your where clause like that.

So try this instead:

```
$products = Product::whereHas('colors', function(Builder $query) 
    { 
        $query->groupBy('color_id', 'product_id')
              ->havingRaw('count(color_id) > 3');
    })
    ->with('colors') // eager load them
    ->get();
```

It might not work as I can't try it, but I hope it will give you an idea at least on how to perform this.

Otherwise use the filter on the [collection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-filter) instance.

So something like this maybe:

```
$products = Product::has('colors')->with('colors') 
    ->get()
    ->filter(function($item) {
        return $item->colors->count() >= 3;
    });
```

Comment: There is no need for this line `->with('colors') // eager load them` of code because laravel will eager load the colors from behind the scenes. I have tested it myself.

Comment: @kellymandem laravel will not eager load them by itself, either you already loaded them or you dont understand how eager loading works. check https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

Comment: The second solution (filtering on collection) is a bad suggestion for inexperienced developers. you should remove it.

Comment: @N69S I have tried it on my own data using `Laravel 5.5 sample blog project` using the relationship between `posts` and `tags` and the tags are eager loaded just fine using the same query builder flow.

Comment: @kellymandem for that you need to set the attribute `protected $eagerload` on the model. Any way, this is not the place to discuss this, you can join me in https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200552/laravel-eager-loading for that